# Creating a graph efficiently

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am trying to write a graph given vertices coordinates, where the edges are created if they lie within a radius. The function below works well for a small number of vertices; however, it takes forever if the number of vertices is larger than 15. Any suggestion on how to speed it up will be highly appreciated.

```
def setup_domain():
x_dom = 0, Length, Nx
y_dom = 0, Width,  Ny
z_dom = 0, Depth,  Nz
lin_x = np.linspace(x_dom[0], x_dom[1], x_dom[2])
lin_y = np.linspace(y_dom[0], y_dom[1], y_dom[2])
lin_z = np.linspace(z_dom[0], z_dom[1], z_dom[2])
domEn = np.zeros((Nx * Ny * Nz, 3))
c = 0
for z in np.nditer(lin_z):
    for x in np.nditer(lin_x):
        tb = y_dom[2] * c
        te = tb + y_dom[2]
        c += 1
        domEn[tb:te, 0] = x
        domEn[tb:te, 1] = lin_y
        domEn[tb:te, 2] = z

G = create_graph(domEn)
return G

def create_graph(coordinates):
A = np.array(coordinates)
B = squareform(pdist(A))
# print("B=", B)
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(B)
for i in range(len(coordinates)):
    G.add_node(i, coordinates=coordinates[i])
    for j in range(len(coordinates)):
        if G.get_edge_data(i,j) !=None:
            if (G.get_edge_data(i,j)['weight']>dx):
                # print("i=",i, "j=",j)
                G.remove_edge(i,j)

return G
```

Comment: This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66712914/2912349) may be helpful.

Comment: @ravenspoint The method used in the linked answer, `query_ball_point` returns all points within the specified `dist`, not the k nearest neighbours. Plain KD-trees are plenty fast, and there are implementations in the "standard" packages (scipy & scikit-learn).

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Since the OP has a 3D problem I would recommend an octree ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree ) which is a kind of KD tree optimized for 3D.  I cannot tell what you mean by "plenty fast" ( nor by the OP's "takes forever" ).  I have not implemented an octree myself, but my quadtree implementation requires 4 milliseconds to construct a 10,000 2D point tree and finds the neighbors of a point in a mean time of 3 microseconds.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen, Many thanks for the reply. The current implementation is faster than the approach discussed in the link. The one posted above takes 27 s for 3700 points while the one in the link you shared takes 523 s.  The issue is that I need a way larger number of points, where I need to run it multiple times

Comment: @AbuStack  My comment describes the kind of performance you should expect.  It is for 2D point, so for 3D I would guess you can expect a performance that would be twice as long.

Comment: @ravenspoint, many thanks for the suggestion. Are there any examples for octree or quadtree you are aware of? I never used them, so having a sample code will be helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: @AbuStack  I think the Wikipedia article I linked to has examples.  My own code is in C++.  An out of date version of my quadtree C++ code is open source - you can see it at https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree

Comment: FYI I have updated the open source code.  The readme has more details from the performance test

Comment: You report a performance of 27 s for 3700 points.  It isn't clear what exactly this is, but it seems very poor.  Doing a linear search through a vector of points, calculating the distance to a specified point and storing the ones that meet a threshold surely cannot take so long.  In C++ I can do this in 20 milliseconds for 5,000 points.  I know python is kind of slow ( which is why I do not use it ) but this is surprising.

Comment: @ravenspoint, thanks. This is the implementation I have. I believe that there are more efficient ones. But, I fully agree. C++ is faster than python

Comment: FYI I have added an implementation of octree.  Testing is not complete, so I have not merged it into the master - if interested you will find the code in the "3D" development branch of the quadtree repo (  github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree ).  It is very similar to the quadtree.  If nothing comes up tomorrow, I will complete testing and add a performance test for a 5000 point cloud.

Comment: Thanks, @ravenspoint. Sadly, I don't know C++. I have to learn it one day though.

Comment: My octree code is tested and the performance results are in.  Building a 5000 3D point tree needs 24 millisecs and searching for the neighbours of a point needs 3 microsecs

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an octree ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree ) which is a kind of KD tree optimized for 3D problems.

What sort of performance can you expect?  Many orders of magnitude better than 27 seconds for 3700 points!  ( I am assuming that this is the time to find the neighbors of a random point amidst a cloud of 3700 3D points, starting from scratch each time )

Note that there is an initial cost required to build the tree before you can start searching.

Using hand coded C++, an optimizing compiler, and a middle of the road laptop, then building a tree of ~5000 3D points should take about 24 milliseconds.  Each search for the neighbors of a point should take 3 microseconds.  This is based on the perfomance results of the octree at https://github.com/JamesBremner/quadtree

Full performance results ( all times in microseconds )

| Points | Vector search 1 point neighbors | Quadtree build | Quadtree search 1 point neighbors | Octree build | Octree search |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0.5 | 45 | 0.3 | 64 | 1 |
| 500 | 2 | 161 | 0.4 |  |  |
| 1000 | 5 | 3250 | 1 |  |  |
| 5000 | 20 | 18400 | 1 | 24000 | 3 |
| 10000 | 43 | 40000 | 3 | 55000 | 7 |

Using hand coded Python will take about 50 times longer, depending on how good your coding.  If you can find a good library implementation, you can expect performance comparable to the C++ code ( many high performance python libraries are coded in C++ )